# How to access parameters that were passed to next page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, e-commerce

As part of my requirement i constructed the href link with a variable associated with it as follows

```
<h5><a href="http://working.artefacts.co.in/single.php?',$ID,'"> ', $NAME, '</a></h5>
```

Upon click, page is being redirected correctly to single.php and even $ID value can be seen on the browser.

But I dont know how to extract ID parameter in single.php

Can any body please tell me how can i access $ID value in single.php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h5><a href="http://working.artefacts.co.in/single.php?id='.$ID.'"> ', $NAME, '</a></h5>

<?php echo $_REQUEST['id']; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I got it now

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like sessions, cookies or GET / POST variables. Sessions and cookies are quite easy to use, with session being by far more secure than cookies. More secure, but not completely secure.

Session:

```
//On page 1
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

Remember to run the session_start() statement on both these pages before you try to access the $_SESSION array, and also before any output is sent to the browser.

Cookie:

```
//One page 1
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];
```

GET and POST

You can either add the variable in the link to the next page:

```
<a href="page2.php?varname=<?php echo $var_value ?>">Page2</a>
```

This will create a GET variable, or include a hidden field in a form that submits to page two:

```
<form method="get" action="page2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="varname" value="var_value">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And then on page two

```
//Using GET
$var_value = $_GET['varname'];

//Using POST
$var_value = $_POST['varname'];

//Using GET, POST or COOKIE.
$var_value = $_REQUEST['varname'];
```

Just change the method for the form to post if you want to do it via post. Both are equally insecure, although GET is easier to hack.

Comment: As a PHP beginner must  have knowledge of above things

Answer (score 0):

[', $NAME, '](http://working.artefacts.co.in/single.php?id=%27.$ID.%27)

PHP $_GET can also be used to collect form data after submitting an HTML form with method="get".

$_GET can also collect data sent in the URL.

Assume we have an HTML page that contains a hyperlink with parameters:

```
<a href="test_get.php?subject=PHP&web=W3schools.com">Test $GET</a>
```

When a user clicks on the link "Test $GET", the parameters "subject" and "web" are sent to "test_get.php", and you can then access their values in "test_get.php" with $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the `$ID` is set to 2, your URL is:

```
http://working.artefacts.co.in/single.php?2
```

So, in your `single.php` page you have to write:

```
$id = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```